# Using a survey on smoking status of parents, it was established that 35% of all parents

Tags: probability, statistics

Using a survey on smoking status of parents, it was established that 35% of all parents are nonsmoking parents of which 7.8% had  children with pneumonia, one parent smoking  percentage is 25% of which 11.4% had children with  pneumonia, and both parent smoking percentage is 40% of which 17.6% had children with  pneumonia. What is the probability that a randomly selected newborn will have  What is the probability that a randomly selected newborn will have  pneumonia?

Comment: Your penultimate sentence is incomplete.  Did you accidentally begin typing the last sentence twice?

Answer (score 0):

The problem uses Bayes' Theorem.
Let $$P(N) :probability\ of\  getting\  a\  children\  with\  pneumonia\\P(P) : probability \ that\ one \ parent\ is\ smoking\\P(nP): probability\ that\ no\ parent\ is\ smoking \\P(PP):probability\ that\ both\ parents\ are\ smoking$$

So,
$$P(N) = P(N|P)*P(P) +P(N|nP)*P(nP) + P(N|PP)*P(PP)\\=.35*.078+ .25*.114+.40*.176\\= 0.1262$$

Comment: Hope, It worked. :)